# How to edit /var/www/html/app/locale/en_US/ves_vendors/main.csv file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, localisation

I am changed main.csv file line no. 180 (Thank you for registering with %s. Your vendor account info is submited for approval.) to replace (Your account is created and will be ready in 15 minutes.). But changes not working its show old message. Please give me right solution to fix it this success message to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing 3rd party files, you should add custom translations to the theme:

Create the following file if it does not exist yet:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

(replace `en_US` if you use a different language)

Note that this should be a project specific theme, not `rwd/default` or `some_bought_theme/default`. If you did not already, you can add a child theme next to `default` and specify this one as theme in the system configuration. You don't need to copy anything from the `default` directory since Magento falls back automatically, so you only need to add the files that are customized.

In the `translate.csv` you can add your custom translations. Add this line:

```
"Thank you for registering with %s. Your vendor account info is submited for approval.","Your account is created and will be ready in 15 minutes."
```

Then don't forget to flush the cache since translations are cached.

Comment: That's good! If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If you found a different solution, you can add it as own answer and mark it as accepted, to help future visitors. Thanks for your contribution